# Vews Load More remember scroll position and take user there after coming back from single node

Tags: ajax, views

im using this plugin for lazy loading images [Views Load More](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_load_more).

So i have page with photos that links to individual nodes, and im using lazy load on it, its a view that loads 15 items per batch, there are some pages that have 1000+ images.

Than when user scrolls and clicks on one image and lets say he is on 135th image, it will link to a related node, on that node i have button "back" and what im trying to accomplish is that user returns on same position where he was before clicking on item in list, so in our case its on ~135th position. Same thing i want to accomplish with browsers back button.

Is this possible to do with this plugin?